# adb wait-for-device not working in jenkins job but working in ssh session

Tags: android, android-emulator, jenkins-pipeline, adb

I have a Mac mini computer running macOS Catalina OS, that is a Jenkins slave running declarative pipelines.

If I connect to ssh and run an emulator with the command:

```
emulator -avd Pixel_2_API_28_-_Android_9 -wipe-data -no-snapshot &
```

and then wait for it to be ready with the command:

```
adb wait-for-device -s emulator-5554 shell 'while [[-z $(getprop sys.boot_completed) ]]; do sleep 1; done;'
```

All works fine, I get the command prompt after some seconds and I can run appium tests locally.

The problem appear, when I run this very same commands (and a lot of similar ones I found digging here and elsewhere that you can see commented out below) as jenkins jobs in my declarative pipelines.

The same 'adb wait-for-device' command hangs until the job reaches its 120 minutes timeout limit.

I have tried the following approaches, this is my 'Waiting start emulator' pipeline stage (the 'DEVICEID' variable is a parameter i get from another job)

```
stage('Waiting start emulator') {
    steps {
        //sh '''
        //    adb -s ''' + DEVICEID + ''' reboot
        //'''
        sh '''
            #!/bin/bash
            #adb wait-for-device -s ''' + DEVICEID + ''' shell 'while [[-z $(getprop sys.boot_completed) ]]; do sleep 1; done;'
            gtimeout 600 adb wait-for-device -s ''' + DEVICEID + ''' shell 'while [[-z $(getprop dev.bootcomplete) ]]; do sleep 1; done;'
            #adb wait-for-device -s ''' + DEVICEID + ''' shell 'while [[-z $(getprop dev.bootcomplete) ]]; do sleep 1; done;'
        '''
        /*sh '''
            #!/bin/bash
            #adb wait-for-device

            A=$(adb -s ''' + DEVICEID + ''' shell getprop sys.boot_completed | tr -d '\r')
            while [ "$A" != "1" ]; do
                sleep 2
                A=$(adb -s ''' + DEVICEID + ''' shell getprop sys.boot_completed | tr -d '\r')
            done

            #adb shell wm dismiss-keyguard
            #adb -s ''' + DEVICEID + ''' shell input keyevent 82
        '''*/
        /*sh '''
            #!/bin/bash
            #adb wait-for-device

            #while [ "`adb -s ''' + DEVICEID + ''' shell getprop sys.boot_completed | tr -d '\r' `" != "1" ] ; do sleep 1; done

            #adb shell wm dismiss-keyguard
            #adb -s ''' + DEVICEID + ''' shell input keyevent 82
        '''*/
        //sh '''sleep 30'''
    }
}
```

And here is the start emulator section:

```
stage('Run Emulator') {
    steps {
        sh '''
            #!/usr/bin/env bash

            # Start adb daemon
            adb start-server

            # Start android emulator
            emulator -avd ''' + AVDEMULATOR + ''' -wipe-data -no-snapshot &
        '''
    }
}
```

Is there another method I haven't found yet?

Thanks in advance!